# What are the challenging benchmarks for self driving cars object detection beside Kitti

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, self-driving

I am working on 3D object detection in the context of self driving cars and I was wondering if there are other challenging benchmarks for this beside [Kitti](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/).

Answer (score 1):

You may find [Apolloscape dataset](http://apolloscape.auto/index.html) interesting. It was recently released by Baidu. From the [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.06184) describing the dataset:

> In this paper, we present a large-scale open dataset,
>   ApolloScape, that
>   consists of RGB videos and corresponding dense 3D point
>   clouds.

Apart from the [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.06184),
there have been [some blog posts](https://medium.com/@Synced/baidu-apollo-releases-massive-self-driving-dataset-teams-up-with-berkeley-deepdrive-5e785ab4053b) with summarized information on the dataset.